# manage kiosk saved data

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I'm building a kiosk and now the client wants the kiosk to save the number of clicks the user makes to a page. I was told to initialize sharedobject the first time it's used and then increment the sharedobject page clicks. Then you can make another app to display the results.

Being I never seen this done before, can anyone offer any advice or links to how this would be done? Basic scripting please, no flex or OOP.

Comment: All the examples regarding SO you can find in official language reference. But I really wonder how you will access that SO from another app.

Comment: The problem I'm having with using the official language is finding the data sent to the computer. Does it only work when the site is live? When I do a test movie and use the flush, I can't find the data anywhere in the #sharedobject folder. Just a bunch of old website files. I would like to assign the clicks this to a text document, but this is difficult.

Comment: I'm afraid you can not read SO of one swf/app from another. So try to look more into AIR development where you can access file system in order to write to text file or even to local database(SQLite). But with "Basic scripting please, no flex or OOP" attitude you won't do anything, so either you're trying to learn something or hire someone to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Though unofficial, this website http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashSharedObject/index.html pretty much sums it all up.

Please find the official documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Some basic googling would have done the job for you as well.

Cheers